# How to write a api call in node js

Tags: node.js, postman

I have a function written in node js. When that function ends, at the end I am calling another function. Mostly those functions, I am using GitHub API to read and write from my repo.

So it includes a series of API calls and it is working. It takes around 8 - 10 seconds for it to complete all the API calls.

Now, I am expecting that instead of running that function from the VS code terminal using "node {filename}", I want to make it an API.

So when I hit the API URL from the postman, this function should run.

This is what I am looking to do now. Can someone point me in the right direction like how to convert this node js function to an API and run that from postman?

I tried this syntax from youtube,

```
var common = require("./commonMethods");
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  res.write(()=>{
const promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let repoName = "sample";
   var status =  common.createRepo(repoName);
   var status1 =  common.getRepoContents(repoName);
   console.log(status);
   console.log(status1);
})
}
);
  res.end();
}).listen(4000);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What is the issue are you facing from what you have tried till now?

Comment: I am having a function,  and i am running that function from terminal. But instead of running from terminal, i want to call that function when a api call is made.

Comment: look you need to run your code in order to get a response from your API.  You can upload your code somewhere else and then they will run your code on their servers. In that case, you don't need to run your js code on your terminal.